# circular collection view layout

Tags: ios, objective-c

im trying to make a collection view that is circular in shape.

[image: this is what im trying to do]

Somehow I managed to get the view circular, but stuck with scrolling. my collection view cells and layout are circular but I'm not able to make the cells scrollable.

```
`#import "CircleLayout.h"

#define ITEM_SIZE 70

@interface CircleLayout()

// arrays to keep track of insert, delete index paths
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *deleteIndexPaths;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths;

@end

@implementation CircleLayout
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;

}
-(id)init
{
    if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;
    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(60.0, 200.0);
    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 60, 0, 60);
    self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    return self;
}
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(60.0, 200.0);
        self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 60, 0, 60);
        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)prepareLayout
{
    [super prepareLayout];

    CGSize size = self.collectionView.frame.size;
    _cellCount = [[self collectionView] numberOfItemsInSection:0];
    _center = CGPointMake(size.width, size.height);
    _radius = MIN(size.width, size.height)/1.3f;

}

-(CGSize)collectionViewContentSize
{
    return [self collectionView].frame.size;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:path];
    attributes.size = CGSizeMake(ITEM_SIZE, ITEM_SIZE);
    attributes.center = CGPointMake(_center.x + _radius * cosf(2 * path.item * M_PI / _cellCount),
                                    _center.y + _radius * sinf(2 * path.item * M_PI / _cellCount));
    return attributes;
}

-(NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSMutableArray* attributes = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSInteger i=0 ; i < self.cellCount; i++) {
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
        [attributes addObject:[self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    }
    return attributes;
}



- (void)prepareForCollectionViewUpdates:(NSArray *)updateItems
{
    // Keep track of insert and delete index paths
    [super prepareForCollectionViewUpdates:updateItems];

    self.deleteIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.insertIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (UICollectionViewUpdateItem *update in updateItems)
    {
        if (update.updateAction == UICollectionUpdateActionDelete)
        {
            [self.deleteIndexPaths addObject:update.indexPathBeforeUpdate];
        }
        else if (update.updateAction == UICollectionUpdateActionInsert)
        {
            [self.insertIndexPaths addObject:update.indexPathAfterUpdate];
        }
    }
}

- (void)finalizeCollectionViewUpdates
{
    [super finalizeCollectionViewUpdates];
    // release the insert and delete index paths
    self.deleteIndexPaths = nil;
    self.insertIndexPaths = nil;
}

// Note: name of method changed
// Also this gets called for all visible cells (not just the inserted ones) and
// even gets called when deleting cells!
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath
{
    // Must call super
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];

    if ([self.insertIndexPaths containsObject:itemIndexPath])
    {
        // only change attributes on inserted cells
        if (!attributes)
            attributes = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];

        // Configure attributes ...
        attributes.alpha = 0.0;
        attributes.center = CGPointMake(_center.x, _center.y);
    }

    return attributes;
}

// Note: name of method changed
// Also this gets called for all visible cells (not just the deleted ones) and
// even gets called when inserting cells!
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath
{
    // So far, calling super hasn't been strictly necessary here, but leaving it in
    // for good measure
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];

    if ([self.deleteIndexPaths containsObject:itemIndexPath])
    {
        // only change attributes on deleted cells
        if (!attributes)
            attributes = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];

        // Configure attributes ...
        attributes.alpha = 0.0;
        attributes.center = CGPointMake(_center.x, _center.y);
        attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
    }

    return attributes;
}
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
    return YES;
}
@end
```

`

Comment: Try This.. https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel . customize iCarouselTypeInvertedWheel of this iCarousel according to your needs. May it will help you.

Comment: @MeetDoshi thank you buddy for your response. i will try it out .
By the way i got it done using https://github.com/sarn/ARNRouletteWheelView/blob/master/ARNRouletteWheelView.podspec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have developed an custom UICollectionviewLayout, which layout's the collection view cells in an circular layout. It can be configured to show an particular.

In your case you would be needing an 180 - 90 degrees with centre bottom right.

https://github.com/DoddaSrinivasan/DSCircularCollectionView